# Fully case insensitive org property search

Tags: org-mode, search, case-folding

I would like to be able to perform fully case insensitive searches of properties and their values in my org files, and have the results presented in a sparse tree.

For example, if I have sections where the property name is FOO and the property value is bar, I would like to be able to produce a sparse tree consisting of all sections having a property named foo (case insensitive) and the value is bar (again, regardless of case).

I have tried `org-sparse-tree` `m` and doing a search like my_prop="my_val". This seems to work for the property name (which can be MY_PROP or my_prop in the results) but searching for my_val will not return sections where the value is MY_VAL.

I have also tried `org-ql-sparse-tree` using `property:MY_PROP,my_val` but this only returns results where the property name and value match case-wise.